# How to use KBinsDiscretizer with defined bin edges

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I need to discretize one column in my dataframe according to the following bin edges

```
[ -1.4968, 2.546612, 3.612398, 6.18902]
```

I see how to create the KBinsDiscretizer object but how to ask it to use my predefined bins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KBinsDiscretizer determines the cut-points according to the strategy selected. If you have predefined bin edges you can use [pandas.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) or [numpy.digitize()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html).